# Tao Analysis 1 Exercise 3.4.2

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. Let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and $U$ be a subset of $Y$.

(iii) In general, what's the relation between $f^{-1}f^{-1}(U)$ and $U$?

Need help for 3.4.2 (iii). My solutions to part(i) and part(ii) are in general that there are no relation except in certain cases such as when f is bijective.

For part(iii), I thought it might be something similar but I tried to think of a couple of counterexamples and they all failed in some way or another so I thought that it may be the case that for (iii) both sets are always the same. I tried to proof it as below but got stuck and am not sure how to proceed. If f is injective, then clearly it works but in general im not sure how to proceed.

Let $x$ be an element of $f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(U)))$, then there must exist $y \in f(f^{-1}(U))$, such that $f(x) = y$. For such $y$ to exist, there must also exist some $z \in f^{-1}(U)$, such that $f(z) = y$.

Comment: Please don't post unsearchable images of text and equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same set for an arbitrary $f$.

The inclusion $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(U)))$ is a consequence of what you already have seen in (i).

Conversely, let $x\in f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(U)))$. Thus, $f(x)\in f(f^{-1}(U))$ so there exists $z\in f^{-1}(U)$ such that $f(x)=f(z)$. Now, since $z\in f^{-1}(U)$ then $f(z)\in U$, hence $f(x)\in U$. Therefore, $x\in f^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: ah i got part(i) wrong so i wasn’t able to see the inclusion in that direction. 
Could i also check that for part(ii),  the relation is that $f(f^{-1}U) \subseteq U$

For the converse part, I understand now, it was sufficient to show that $f(z)=f(x)$ even if $z$ and $x$ are different since that allows us to say that $f(x) \in U$ and conclude that the pre-image of $U$ under $f$ will contain $x$

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you know about the relationship between  $f^{-1}(f(S))$ and $S$ as in the previous exercises. What happens when $S = f^{-1}(U)$ in that scenario?

I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: I dont think its equivalent though,  since there are some cases where (i) is true, and i feel like $S=f^{-1}U$ is precisely such a case.

Comment: ah nvm i think i got part(i) and part(ii) wrong which is why i didnt understand what you meant